# Azure analytics insight - issue with user flow display

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We created a user flow, that displays both custom event (click-event) and page views.
Our issue is that the tool only displays the event name (see attached)[User flow example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swG5n.png)

We want to understand
1)Is there a way to display in the user flow module other properties and not the generic name?
If not:
2) how to create a custom user flow query, to show custom event parameters?
not just event-name but all custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and as per this [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-flows) and [User flows](https://dailydotnettips.com/user-flows-in-application-insights/) Documents you can create custom events and pull data from custom events to user flows but you can create a custom query for User flows you can just add the listed filters in it

[image]